# MySQL Update Where Field is Different

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question about a MySQL query. I would (obviously) like to use as few queries as possible for this, and hopefully just one. What I'm trying to do is update a column in the database if the info is different.

For example, say I have the column "referer" and the column "date". If the user clicks the link and the referer is different but the date is the same, I would like to update only the referer column.

This is my current query:

```
mysql_query ("
  UPDATE clicks 
  SET 
    clicks = clicks + 1
  , referers = CONCAT(referers, ',$referer')
  , dates = CONCAT(dates, ',$date')
  WHERE shortURL = '$url' 
  AND referer != $referer
");
```

Is there any way to work this into one query?

Comment: Apart from the query, it's impossible for the date to be the same, time is running!

Comment: Why are you storing multiple values in the `referers` and `dates` columns?  This is inefficient, since those columns will hold enormous strings for pages that have a large number of clicks.  It also makes it much harder to figure out the top referrers or most-clicked pages for a particular date.

Comment: So it would be more efficient to just create a new row for every click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read something about database normalization.
first normalization rule is: fields have to be atomic. in your case: don't save multiple referers/dates into one field separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the normalization answer, but if you insist .. it sounds like you need a CASE statement:

```
UPDATE clicks
SET 
  clicks = clicks + 1
, referers = CONCAT(referers, ',$referer')
, dates = 
   CASE
     WHEN dates REGEXP '/$date/' THEN dates
     ELSE CONCAT(dates, ',$date')
   END CASE
WHERE shortURL = '$url' 
AND referers NOT REGEXP '/$referer/'
```

Note: This assumes $referer and $date don't have any special regex chars!